# Regex. 12 hour time format PHP only allow - 'g:i A'

Tags: php, regex

I am just learning regexes - and have come up with the following PHP regex which I believe works:

```
/^([1-9]|1[012]):([0-5][0-9]) ((A|P)M)$/
```

I wish to allow the following string only when validating:

```
1-12:00-59 AM/PM
```

To better describe requirements, I need a regex for the following PHP date format

```
g:i A
```

Is there a good tool I can use to test this regex? Does anybody have a better regex for me to use?

Comment: There are plenty of on-line regex testers you can Google for.  Why not just test in your code through.  Run some sample with values that should and should not validate and see what you get.  Make sure to test edge cases.

Comment: Looks fine to me except you probably don't want to allow *both* `0` and `12`

Comment: @ExplosionPills - What about `0:30 AM`? Thirty minutes past midnight?

Comment: @Gravy that would be `12:30 AM`.  `0-23` is fine for a 24-hour clock, but `0-12` doesn't make sense

Comment: @Gravy: The 12 hour format starts is from 1 to 12, so `00:30 AM` should be invalid.

Comment: @AmalMurali - Thanks, ExplosionPills already pointed this out - my silly mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex isn't well suited for parsing dates. Use PHP's DateTime class instead (function by [Glavić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67332/), from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php#113205])):

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'g:i A')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

Comment: +1 for discourage from RegExp. Personally, I'd use native `date` / `strtotime` functions.

Comment: @matewka Yes you can use date/strtotime, but I very much applaud the use of DateTime here.  Every PHP developer should learn and use this (and related classes) as they provide much more power/flexibility and an OO-based interface.

Comment: @AmalMurali - Thanks for this, I should have mentioned however that I am stuck using the https://github.com/vlucas/valitron/ validation class. They have a date validator, but as not so well documented for time specifically, I opted for a regex to solve this problem. Good to know for the future however.

Comment: In the meantime, I will also be experimenting with the valitron class - I may be able to set up the following rule: 'dateFormat' => [['appointment_time', 'g:i A']] as it appears to use the `date_parse_from_format` function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php